# pin button position error html

Tags: html, button

button pin position goes, as soon as you load the js.
There is no modification to justify his position ..
So use proof.
http://abrakahasba.hu/recept/63/Almas-pite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises just because of the `vertical-align` problem. You are using `inline-block` to display contents, so it will assume all `a`'s as vertically centered. But except pin button, you have not set the `vertical-align` style to any of the button.
 So, add just a single code into your stylesheet.

```
social a { vertical-align:top; }
```